# Magento2: How to redirect to payment section checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, redirect-url

I am trying add code for redirect  `$this->resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/index/index#payment');`

but some reason its take slash at the end of url so url become `www.demo.com/checkout/index/index#payment/`

which give me 404. if I pass `www.demo.com/checkout/index/index#payment` it work.

in-short I am getting addition slash at the end after parameter.

Comment: You might  be getting JS error

Comment: @AmitBera No there is not any error as data is already pre-set in quote but i am getting 404 due to / at last www.demo.com/checkout/index/index#payment/

Answer (score 3):

> Below code worked for me

```
 $this->_redirect('checkout', ['_fragment' => 'payment']);
```

Comment: Thank you Hitesh, this solved my same problem.
One related thing though, is there a way to send an error message to the checkout/#payment?
Tried with the MessageManager but doesn't do anything.